# Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement with Spring Boot default configuration

Tags: java, spring

This is error which I get when I try to run the Spring Boot app as java app:
`org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement`
`Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'SA' does not exist`

I have tride to change hibernate dialect in propereties in pom.xml (like written in other simillar topics about this problem) but it didn't help. I have also tried to change names of Topic class and fields.
This is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.julian.boot3</groupId>
    <artifactId>boot3</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>boot3</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Main class:

```
package com.julian.spring;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

POJO:

```
package com.julian.spring.pojo;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="topics")
public class Topic {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public Topic() {

    }

    public Topic(int id, String name, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'SA' does not exist, what don't you understand ? It's better to provide your app config too.

Comment: How to provide my app config? I didn't changeany  configuration, this is default.

Comment: where is your connection to database ?

Comment: I don't know. This is spring boot app with apache.derby

Comment: You have to create app config in resources folder.

Comment: and what should I write there? I follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3HnFBzn7DI&index=29&t=201s&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTbx8p2oCgcAQGQyqN8XeA1x and the author didn't change any configuration in `application.properties` file. This is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in **application.properties** file under resources:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by downgrading version of spring-boot-starter-parent fomr 2.0.4.REALESE to 1.5.1.RELEASE

Answer (score -1):

Please read https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/ this, is so regular question, how to arrange connection to database.

If you are not using MySQL, there are article for other databases, but for relational databases, all are the same.

Comment: so why the man in the tutorial didn't need to connect to any database? and it works for him.

Comment: Have you seen all him videos?

Comment: till this problem, yes.

Comment: You can create db in memory, but it is needed for repo tests, please, click link, that I've attached to post, read about this, and it will help your in the future.

Comment: Obviously it is asking for a SQL server, and the answer is very generic and has nothing to do with SQL server, this answer does not help much.